# Adding Rails Database Table Column values in ApplicationRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I am not so big on Ruby Logic. So i have a `Users` Table with many `portfolios`, The portfolios Table has an `amount` column. I want to add the total amount of for each users portfolio to the users model and I also want it to skip for users portfolio with `nil` values in the portfolios.

i did something like this

#this is my user activerecord

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :assets
    has_many :portfolios

    validates :email, :first_name, :last_name, presence: true
    validates :email, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
    validates :password, length: { in: 6..20 }

    def total_asset
        portfolios.amount.sum
    end
end
```

and this is my portfolio active record

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :asset
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I get internal error. Like I said earlier I want to skip and avoid adding portfolios amounts with `nil` value

Answer (score 0):

ok i was able to come up with this easy solution after trying to understand the Ruby syntax

```
def total_asset
        
        portfolios.collect{|portfolio| portfolio.valid? ? portfolio.amount : 0}.sum
    end
```

this would skip invalid or non existant columns

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing this in Ruby.

The efficient way to do this is to use an aggregate function in the database:

```
User.group(:id)
    .left_joins(:portfolios)
    .select(
      User.arel_table[Arel.star], # all the columns from users
      Portfolio.arel_table[:amount].sum.as("portfolio_amount") # the aggregated count
    )
```

This avoids creating a n+1 query every time the `#total_asset` method is called and avoids pull all the data out of the portfolios table. If you want to further optimize this for reads you can cache the aggregate count on the users table either by using [callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) or the [counter_culture gem](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture).